# IT Hit WebDAV .NET server with filenames containing ampersands (&)

Tags: ithit-webdav-server

We are using IT Hit WebDAV .NET Server v6.1.4325 and experience an issue with filenames containing an ampersand (&):

When a request containing filename with an ampersand hits WebDAV’s `GetHierarchyItemAsync` method in `DavContext.cs`, the filename gets lost in the path parameter. Filenames without “&” work fine. I have tried escaping it with `%26` without a success.

I could see that a similar bug was fixed for AjaxBrowser v3.0.0.2480 on July 11, 2016.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue or knows a solution/workaround?

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing web server's logs, I found out that the problem is in HttpException thrown by the server:

`A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&)`

This can be solved by removing the `&` character from a list of `requestPathInvalidCharacters` under `httpRuntime` element in Web.config:

`<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,:,\,?" />`